# CSS: Google Chrome doing strange things with inline-block on centred UL element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some strange and disturbing things happening on Chrome with UL elements set to `display:inline-block;`

On MY screen, it seems to display absolutely fine each and every time:

[image: My Working Example]

However on my colleagues Chrome browser (same version):

[image: Not Working Example]

What's disturbing about it, is that if he brings up developer console and simply turns `display:inline-block;` off and on again, it works!

Here's my live example - http://jsfiddle.net/Bsm4t/

Anyone have any idea what on earth is causing it, or how I might possibly debug it or even fix it?

Oh and here's some code snippet for if the link stops working:

HTML:

```
<div>
<p>Pulse will enable you to manage your mobile assets in a way that no other solution on the market currently offers. Pulse comprises of the following 3 modules:</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/product-portfolio/enterprise-mobility/pulse/live-planning-and-execution.html"><strong>Live Planning and Execution</strong></a></li>
</ul>
<p>Manage resources in real-time using detailed maps and user friendly applications</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="/product-portfolio/enterprise-mobility/pulse/mobility-pulse-mobile.html"><strong>Mobility – Pulse Mobile</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One|Fjord+One|Imprima|Reenie+Beanie);

div {
    width:80%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: "Imprima", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
* {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
ul, ol {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul li,
ol li {
    margin:0 0 5px 0;   
    list-style-position:inside;
}
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
   padding:0;
   margin:30px 0 0 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing list-style-position: inside; seems to fix it for me. Or if you deliberately need to have that inside position, you can still have it as display block and make it work:

```
ul, ol {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Good find! That does stop the Chrome awkwardness, although making it `list-style-position: outside;` makes them just off centre :/

Comment: Can't do what you've suggested unfortunately. When you have more than one in the list, they don't sit nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/Bsm4t/1/. Leaving how it was does: http://jsfiddle.net/Bsm4t/2/

Comment: By "sit nicely", do you mean that you want the lists to be centered  but inside each individual bullet point the text is left-aligned?

Comment: Indeed, sorry I didn't make it clear. It seems changing it to `list-style-position: outside;` is the best way to achieve this, even if it does make them appear slightly off-centre.

Comment: The problem could also be, because you use "inline-block" the ul doesn't really know how wide it should be, perhaps give it a width, and then you can center it with margin. http://jsfiddle.net/kasperoo/Bsm4t/3/

Comment: That does seem to be the problem, unfortunately I can't give it a width because it's dynamic content...

Answer (score 1):

Where you have set  `list-style-position: inside` you haven't made the elements bigger to account for the bullet point being in the element.

Either remove  `list-style-position: inside` although since you've set this property you probably want to keep it so if you make the element wider than default and it will fit without wrapping.